# Tagging a Docker image with auto incremented global version in Gitlab in yaml

Tags: docker, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm currently digging in Gitlab CI. I would like to add a way in my YAML files to tag my docker images with a version number composed in the following fashion : MajorVersion.Minorversion.AutoincrementedGlobalversionNumber

I would like to auto-increment the globally defined variable "AutoincrementedGlobalversionNumber" each time I deploy.

I have used CI_PIPELINE_IID however it keeps incrementing for each pipeline request, I need something to keep a version where I can keep track of and it should increment only when I pack and deploy.

```
   variables:
      CI_VERSION: "1.0.${CI_PIPELINE_IID}"

    build-master:
      stage: build
      script:
        - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_VERSION"   ./postfix
        - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
      only:
        - master
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't do this with the default [GitLab CI variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/), but there could be a workaround along the lines of (untested):

1. Get the registry ID with something like:

   `$ registry_id=$(curl -s -XGET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/$PROJECT_PATH/container_registry.json" | jq '.[].id')`
2. Query said registry to get the name:

   `curl -s -XGET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/$PROJECT_PATH/registry/repository/$registry_id/tags?format=json" | jq`

   eg returns the following and you can grep the name for `GlobalVersionNumber`:

   ```
   [
     {
       "name": "latest",
       "location": "registry.gitlab.com/mwasilewski/helm:latest",
       "revision": "85a403337a56e9e6409dfb8185bf9aa5c2135f9a437bd75da82d27471c71feb4",
       "short_revision": "85a403337",
       "total_size": 152246865,
       "created_at": "2016-12-11T08:31:30.126+00:00",
       "destroy_path": "/mwasilewski/helm/registry/repository/31074/tags/latest"
     }
   ]
   ```
3. Continue with your Docker build and push, after incrementing the `GlobalVersionNumber` you get back.

NB: this assumes you are using [GitLab's Container Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/container_registry.html)

Resources:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/40826